# PCA result interpretation

Tags: r, pca

I'm studying PCA and I'm trying to apply this method to mtcars dataset in R. This is my code:

```
library(usethis)
library(devtools)
library(ggbiplot)  

mtcars.pca <- prcomp(mtcars[,c(1:7,10,11)], center = TRUE,scale. = TRUE)
mtcars.country <- c(rep("Japan", 3), rep("US",4), rep("Europe", 7),rep("US",3), "Europe", rep("Japan", 3), rep("US",4), rep("Europe", 3), "US", rep("Europe", 3))
ggbiplot(mtcars.pca,ellipse=TRUE,  labels=rownames(mtcars), groups=mtcars.country)
    
# Results for Variables
res.var <- get_pca_var(mtcars.pca)
res.var$coord          # Coordinates
res.var$contrib        # Contributions to the PCs
res.var$cos2           # Quality of representation

# Results for individuals
res.ind <- get_pca_ind(mtcars.pca)
res.ind$coord          # Coordinates
res.ind$contrib        # Contributions to the PCs
res.ind$cos2           # Quality of representation
```

what is the meaning of the `res.var$contrib`? how can I interpret this values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by your comment, the `contrib` column holds all the contributions to the principal components. What this means more specifically is explained well by user chl in [this answer on PCA an variable contributions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/495479):

> If you have a "PCA" object constructed using `FactoMineR::PCA`, then
> variable contribution values are stored in the `$var$contrib` slot of
> your object. The contribution is a scaled version of the squared
> correlation between variables and component axes (or the cosine, from
> a geometrical point of view) --- this is used to assess the quality of
> the representation of the variables of the principal component, and it
> is computed as  $\text{cos}(\text{variable}, \text{axis})^2 \times 100$ / total $\text{cos}^2$ of the component.

In other words, it shows how much each variable contributes to the creation each principal component. The value is a percentage and all values for each principal component add up to 100%.